# Где хранится виртуальное адресное пространство в ОС Windows ?

Tags: windows, архитектура

Каждый процесс имеет свое виртуальное адресное пространство, а ОС уже преобразует эти адреса в реальную физическую память в оперативке. Я прочитал, что виртуальное адресное пространство представлено в виде страниц, также это адресное пространство в 32-битной системе может быть не больше 4 гигабайт
Где хранятся эти страницы и как происходит все это взаимодействие с реальной памятью ?

Answer (score 0):

Сами страницы могут храниться в оперативной памяти или же могут быть выгружены в файл подкачки. Информация о том, как отображается виртуальная память на физическую, хранится для каждого процесса отдельно в специальных таблицах, это внутренние данные системы.

Всё взаимодействие проходит через менеджер памяти, который выделяет и освобождает страницы, а так же осуществляет работу с файлом подкачки.

Подробно про управление памятью в Windows можно прочитать в [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366779(v=vs.85).aspx).